# Virtuoso getting slow after bulk insert. Checkpoint doesn't work

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I have simple SPARQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE { ?class ?sp_1 owl:Class. ?sp_1 rdf:singletonPropertyOf rdf:type. }
```

It has stable execution time - 200ms.

But after bulk import, the time increases to 700ms (sometimes to 1.2s, and to 10 seconds).

Nothing helps. I've tried `checkpoint`, `commit work`, `txn_killall`, restart virtuoso server. But if I wait for several hours, the execution time becomes small again.. 200ms :)

In Conductor monitor, I have no running threads, CPU 100% available.

Is there any hack, or command, that I don't know? Thx :)

Comment: What is the property `rdf:singletonPropertyOf`?

Comment: And I guess this is more a question of the Virtuoso mailing since are asking for configuring the triple store.

Comment: At a guess, free-text and other indexes are being built in the "several hours". Checking that you're on a current version (7.2.4.2 or later, [Open Source](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews) or [Commercial](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/)) is always a good starting point. [Tuning for performance](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning) is a good next step. [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) is a good place to ask about such things.